# CreateSignedURL failure AWS SSE-C with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I have been using AWS SDK V3 for PHP to put object to S3 with Server side encryption using customer provided key. The documentation is quite sketchy (or at least I havent found it).

For uploading the object using the S3client, I use putobject with

```
        $params['SSECustomerAlgorithm'] = 'AES256';
        $params['SSECustomerKey'] = $this->encryptioncustkey;
        $params['SSECustomerKeyMD5'] = $this->encryptioncustkeymd5;
```

The  $this->encryptioncustkey is a plain customer key (not base64_encoded because the SDK seems to be doing that) and this->encryptioncustkeymd5 = md5($this->encryptioncustkey,true);

The put object works fine. However, the problem is in generating a createSignedURL.

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key'    => $storedPath,
            'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment;charset=utf-8;filename="'.utf8_encode($fileName).'"',
            'ResponseContentType' => $ctype,  
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm' => 'AES256',
            'SSECustomerKey' => $this->encryptioncustkey,
            'SSECustomerKeyMD5' => $this->encryptioncustkey64md5
    ));
```

but I get a weird response indicating that it is missing "x-amz-server-side-encryption" (ServerSideEncryption) which according to documentation is not required for SSE-C. Even if I set it to ServerSideEncryption='AES256' it has no effect.

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with Customer provided keys must    provide an appropriate secret key.
</Message>
<ArgumentName>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>null</ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>A3368F6CE5DD310D</RequestId>
<HostId>
nHavXXz/gFOoJT0tnh+wgFTbTgGdpggRkyb0sDh07H7SomcX7HrcKU1dDzgZimrQwyaVQEqAjdk=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and tried every possible permutation to try to get it to work.  I finally concluded that **this use case is not supported**.  Reading through the scattered and arcane documentation on the subject, it seems the only way to access SSE-C content on S3 is by specifying the `x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm`/`x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key`/`x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5` fields **in the HTTP request header**, not in the URL.

What I ended up doing is to store the content in question in S3 **unencrypted** and with the ACL set to `private` (you could upload it as such from the get go, or use `copyObject()` to make a copy with those settings).  Then, when I wanted to get the ["time-bombed"] pre-signed URL for the GET request, I just used the command similar to the one in your question, but omitting the SSE parameters.  That worked for me.